# HTMLElement or document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am learning Javascript, and I figured that there are two simple ways to create HTML elements: `HTMLElement` and `document.createElement`.
Is one of these two deprecated, and if not which one do you think I should use ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot create elements via the HTMLElement object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not create elements with `HTMLElement` so you must use `document.createElement` . `HTMLElement` is just an interface.

Here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . I misunderstood the documentation ><

Answer (score 0):

You should use **document.createElement()**

example :

```
var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.innerText = 'just a random text';
```

and if you want my advice please use **jquery** (**excellent** and **simple** JavaScript library for document traversal and manipulation and much more  )